# Summarise with dplyr - One variable always on bottom

Tags: r, dplyr

Can anyone help me with this? I grouped and summarised spendings data from multiple companies, the output looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    Column1 = c("Other", "Brand1", "Brand2", "Brand3", "Brand4", "Brand5"),
    Column2 = c(NA, "Subbrand1", "Subbrand2", "Subbrand3", "Subbrand4", "Subbrand5"),
    Spendings = c(1000, 500, 250, 200, 150, 100)
)

  Column1   Column2 Spendings
1   Other      <NA>      1000
2  Brand1 Subbrand1       500
3  Brand2 Subbrand2       250
4  Brand3 Subbrand3       200
5  Brand4 Subbrand4       150
6  Brand5 Subbrand5       100
```

The "others" row is on top, however I want that specific column on the bottom, because of later visualization (like here)

```
df <- data.frame(
    Column1 = c("Brand1", "Brand2", "Brand3", "Brand4", "Brand5", "Other"),
    Column2 = c("Subbrand1", "Subbrand2", "Subbrand3", "Subbrand4", "Subbrand5", NA),
    Spendings = c(500, 250, 200, 150, 100, 1000)
)

  Column1   Column2 Spendings
1  Brand1 Subbrand1       500
2  Brand2 Subbrand2       250
3  Brand3 Subbrand3       200
4  Brand4 Subbrand4       150
5  Brand5 Subbrand5       100
6   Other      <NA>      1000
```

This is the function I used to create the df with some desired code of me, which obv. does not work :-(.

```
df <- df%>%
    group_by(Column1, Column2) %>%
    summarise(Spendings = sum(Spendings)) %>%
    arrange(desc(Spendings), lastrow = "others")
```

Is there a way to get the "others" row on bottom inside the dplyr workflow? Subsetting and rbinding is of course possible, but is there a way which suits better?

Comment: I suspect you prefer the order because of `NA` of `Other` in `Column2 `, if that's the case, just `arrange(df, Column2,desc(Spendings))` will list `Other` at bottom. Otherwise try answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a logical vector on `arrange` and this would result in ordering based on alphabetical order i.e. `FALSE` comes before `TRUE`

```
df %>% 
   arrange(Column1 == "Other")
#  Column1   Column2 Spendings
#1  Brand1 Subbrand1       500
#2  Brand2 Subbrand2       250
#3  Brand3 Subbrand3       200
#4  Brand4 Subbrand4       150
#5  Brand5 Subbrand5       100
#6   Other      <NA>      1000
```

---

Another option is to create the column as `factor` with `levels` specified in that order so that 'Other' is the last `level` and if we `arrange` it would be do the order based on the `levels`.  It might be a better option as it would also be maintained while doing the `plot`

```
un1 <- c(setdiff(unique(df$Column1), "Other"), "Other")
df %>%
    mutate(Column1 = factor(Column1, levels = un1)) %>%
    arrange(Column1)
```

---

if we use the `forcats` package, there are some useful functions `fct_relevel` to modify the `levels` easily

```
library(forcats)
df %>% 
  mutate(Column1 = fct_relevel(Column1, "Other", after = Inf)) %>% 
  arrange(Column1)
```

According to the examples in `?fct_relevel`

> Using 'Inf' allows you to relevel to the end when the number
>      of levels is unknown or variable (e.g. vectorised operations)

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- df%>%
group_by(Column1, Column2) %>%
summarise(Spendings = sum(Spendings)) %>%
arrange(Column1=="Other", desc(Spendings))
```